# Specify String In Stored procedure query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that I am running in a stored procedure. However, is produces the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'CHEQUE'
```

The query is:

```
SELECT @QUERY1 = 'UPDATE  [dbo].[ATAB] SET PAYMCODE='CHQ' WHERE RATE=1'
```

How do I specify this string 'CHQ' without getting an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape your single quotes.

```
SELECT @QUERY1 = 'UPDATE  [dbo].[ATAB] SET PAYMCODE=''CHQ'' WHERE RATE=1'
```

Answer (score 4):

When specifying a string literal within a dynamic SQL string you have to escape the single quotation with another single quotation (ex: `''`, not `"` which is double quotation) So the query will be like this:

```
SELECT @QUERY1 = 'UPDATE  [dbo].[ATAB] SET PAYMCODE=''CHQ'' WHERE RATE=1'
```

This will translate it to:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ATAB] SET PAYMCODE='CHQ' WHERE RATE=1
```

You can also use Nate S's answer if you want to store `CHQ` into a variable, or use `EXEC` with specifying parameters like this:

```
DECLARE @Paymcode varchar(3) = 'CHQ'
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Params nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL = N'UPDATE [dbo].[ATAB] SET PAYMCODE=@innerPaymcode WHERE RATE=1'
SET @Params = N'@innerPaymcode varchar(3)'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @innerPaymcode = @Paymcode
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to be different...

```
Declare @PaymMode varchar(3) = 'CHQ';
SELECT @QUERY1 = 'UPDATE [dbo].[ATAB] SET PAYMCODE='+@PaymMode+' WHERE RATE=1';
```

Comment: That could also work, or use `EXEC` with specifying parameters.

Comment: this would also allow the paycode to be updated centrally... not that its needed in this case

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the single quotes in your code

```
SELECT @QUERY1 = 'UPDATE  [dbo].[ATAB] SET PAYMCODE = ''CHQ'' WHERE RATE = 1'
```